# Suppose nine distinct points in $\mathbb P^2(\Bbb C )$ do not all lie on any one line and any line through two of them passes through a third. Show...

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

(From Kirwan's 'Complex Algebraic Curves', chapter 2 q10. Had a search around but can find no solution!)

Show there's a projective transformation taking these points to the points $$\begin{array} \\ [0,1,-1] & [-1,0,1] & [1,-1,0] \\ [0,1,\alpha]& [\alpha,0,1] & [1,\alpha,0] \\ [0,\alpha,1] & [1,0,\alpha] & [\alpha,1,0] \end{array} $$

with ${\alpha^2 - \alpha + 1 = 0}$. Show also that a projective curve of degree 3 passes through these nine points if and only if it is defined by a polynomial of the form

${x^ 3 + y^3 + z^3 + 3\lambda xyz}$

for some ${\lambda \in \mathbb C} $ , and it is singular precisely when

${\lambda \in \{\infty,-1,\alpha,\bar\alpha\} }$

in which case it is the union of 3 lines in $\Bbb{P}^2 .$

$\mathbf{Attempt:}$

My main issue is the first part. I was hoping to show that the nine points could be covered by three lines not all meeting in any one point, which I then showed meant a projective transformation could take those three lines to {x = 0} , {y = 0}, {z = 0}. Then I could get the points to bunch into threes, each set of three having a zero coordinate in one place. The equation in \alpha says it's a cube root of -1, but I'm not sure how come it needs to be. I can see that a curve defined by such a polynomial will hit all of those nine points, and the 'union of three lines' bit is fine. But as for these being \mathbf{all} of the curves passing through all nine points, I'm again stuck.

Would be ever so grateful if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: There must be some further hypotheses about these 9 points. What if 8 of them were on a line and the 9th were not on that line? As you realized, you need to know that the set of 9 points splits into three sets of collinear points.

Comment: Oops! Any line containing two of the points also contains a third. That's the extra hypothesis, thank you.

Comment: There is what essentially amounts of a complete solution here:
http://people.math.umass.edu/~markman/m697_fall04_html/kirwan2-10-hint.pdf